# Целочисленные типы данных C++

Tags: c++, типы-данных

В чём отличие между `long int` - `int`, `signed char` - `__int8` и т.д. отсюда https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s3f49ktz.aspx и почему некоторые функции возвращают `long int`, а другие `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типы данных вроде `int` и `long int` могут иметь различный размер в зависимости от архитектуры. Стандарт лишь ограничивает их относительный размер, например, `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long int)`. Так как неравенство нестрогое, то размеры могут совпадать.

На платформе x86/x64 эти типы имеют вполне конкретный размер, например, `sizeof(int) == 4`. Однако на других архитектурах размер может отличаться.

Разница между `int` и `long int` историческая. На 16-битных платформе `sizeof(int) == 2` и `sizeof(long int) == 4`. Соответственно, для функций тех времён разница существенна.

Типы данных `__int16`, `__int32` имеют гарантированный размер в 16 и 32 бита независимо от архитектуры.

Comment: Получается в компиляторах Visual C++ (32-разрядные и 64-разрядные системы) никаких различий нет? Можно безболезненно присваивать `int`у `long int`?

Comment: @cs1_6 В целом различий нет. Если вы разрабатываете под популярные платформы, то можно плюнуть на нюансы стандарта и рассчитывать на конкретные размеры в байтах. Однако по возможности следует всё-таки избегать неявных приведений типов, потому что они не слишком наглядны. Скажем, в своём коде мешать разные типы одного размера без нужды не надо.

Comment: Просто у меня переменные типа `int`, а функции возвращают `long int`

Comment: Кстати, исправьте "архитектеры"

Comment: Стоит заметить, что использование типа `__int16` и прочих, начинающихся с двойного подчеркивания, отдается на откуп реализации и может быть не переносимо. Для переносимости следует использовать типы из `<cstdint>`, например `std::int16_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Тип `long int` имеет более высокий ранг (даже при равном размере с типом `int`) и обычно более широкий диапазон допустимых чисел (как правило, за счет использования большего количества байтов для внутреннего представления чисел), чем тип `int`. Например, на некоторых платформах тип `long int` может иметь размер равный 8 байтам.

Имеет место cоотношение

```
sizeof( int ) <= sizeof( long )
```

Поэтому в выражениях, где используются операнды типа `long`  и `int`, даже если размер обоих типов совпадает, тем не менее в соответствии с правилами обычных арифметических преобразований объект типа `int` преобразуется к объекту типа `long`, и результат всего выражения будет иметь тип `long`.

Это, например, важно при выборе перегруженной функции.

Рассмотрите следующий пример

```
#include <iostream>

void f( long value ) { std::cout << "f( long ): value = " << value << std::endl; }
void f( int value ) { std::cout << "f( int ): value = " << value << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    long y = -5;

    f( x );
    f( y );
    f( x + y );
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет следующим:

```
f( int ): value = 5
f( long ): value = -5
f( long ): value = 0
```

То есть выражение `x + y`, хотя оно и имеет значение равное 0, тем не менее имеет тип `long` и была вызвана перегруженная функция `f( long )`

Что касается типов `signed char` и `__int8`, то обычно тип `__int8` (это не стандартный тип) определяется как алиас для типа `signed char`. Он вводится для унификации целочисленных типов с фиксированным размером, а не с размером, зависящим от платформы.